# Webscraping: Replacing None values with 0 in a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner building a housing web scraper. I'm building different functions to extract different data (price, url, image, bedrooms, etc.)

I have a problem with bedrooms because some listings do not have bedrooms listed. Could be that it is a plot of land or they forgot to put the number of bedrooms. When the code loops through all the bedrooms in the listings, if it doesn't have a bedroom, this is the error message I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_address.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(get_bedrooms())
  File "get_address.py", line 17, in get_bedrooms
    html_bedrooms = listing.find('h3', {'class': 'listing-results-attr'}).find('span', {'class': 'num-beds'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


    def get_bedrooms():
    
        bedrooms = []
    
        # Finds all the listings_<id> using a regular expression
        for listing in bs.find_all('li', id=re.compile(r'listing.[0-9]+')):
    
            # Finds this code <span class="num-icon num-beds" title="2 bedrooms"><span class="interface"></span>2</span> and stores it in html_bedroom
            html_bedrooms = listing.find('h3', {'class': 'listing-results-attr'}).find('span', {'class': 'num-beds'})
            
            # Extracts the text in the span tags
            no_of_bedrooms = html_bedrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    
            # Updates the empty list with number of bedrooms
            bedrooms.append(no_of_bedrooms)
    
        return bedrooms 
    
    print(get_bedrooms())
```

How do I do a check to see if there is a none type value and then replacing it with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could turn your html_bedrooms assignment into two steps, like this:

```
has_bedrooms = listing.find('h3', {'class': 'listing-results-attr'})
if has_bedroom:
  html_bedrooms = has_bedrooms.find('span', {'class': 'num-beds'})
else:
  html_bedrooms = 0
```

a more pythonic approach might be to ask for forgiveness rather than permission:

```
try:
  html_bedrooms = listing.find('h3', {'class': 'listing-results-attr'}).find('span', {'class': 'num-beds'})
except AttributeError:
  html_bedrooms = 0
```

both of these approaches have the advantage of being easily understandable (either by future you, or anyone you might be working with) with regards to your intent: if we can't find a bedrooms tag, set the number of bedrooms to 0. A list comp like Wasifs answer would also work, but it has less context to someone who's skimming your code for the first time.

Please note this is pseudo code meant to illustrate the 2 approaches, I forget exactly how beautifulsoup works.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into try, except as its the first time I am using it. But it worked.

Comment: Its very useful - errors aren't always "ERRORS" - in this case, an AttributeError just indicates that the property doesn't have bedrooms. Feel free to purposely generate errors in your code when needed, it's 100% allowed :)

Comment: Cool. I think I understand. I had to do another try, except on no_of_bedrooms because it cannot get_text() on a '0' from the previous try, except.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
[0 if x is None else x for x in listing]
```

Will return another list where None is replaced with 0.